# Где учить springframework

Tags: java, spring

Более менее изучил springboot, написав на нем проект тг бота. Теперь хочу спуститься на springframework, но вся гуглежка приводит меня только к springboot. Даже у документации spring не нашел ничего толкового по springframework. Подскажите, где искать информацию, пожалуйста

Comment: Читайте книги. `"Spring для профессионалов" Хо Кларенса` неплохая

Comment: Главная дока тут https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/ Сама по себе она очень неплохая